# insertion in linked list start mid and end

Tags: c++, list, reference, undefined, singly-linked-list

I'm practicing linked list today, trying my best to understand it, so I tried making one singly linked list where I can add at the beginning,middle,and end, it also initializes to add one if the list is empty then printing the result.

I already use functions for this insertion and display of inputs or outputs but still the outputs result to nothing, event the printing the list, i tried to change the position of 
    node* head = NULL; 
and still nothing happens

```
void insert(node* head, int numb, int size, int pos)
{
    node* temp = new node();
    int counter;
    temp->number = numb;
    if (head == NULL) {
        head = temp;
    }
    else {
        int counter = 0;
        node* current = head;
        node* trail = NULL;
        while (counter++) {
            if (counter == pos) {
                temp->next = current;
                trail->next = temp;
                break;
            }
            else {
                trail = current;
                current = current->next;
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    size++;
}
void printlist(node* head)
{
    while (head != NULL) {
        cout << " " << head->number;
        head = head->next;
    }
}
int main()
{
    node* head = NULL;
    int numb, size = 0, pos;
    numb = 5;
    pos = 0;
    insert(head, numb, size, pos);
    printlist(head);
    numb = 6;
    pos = 2;
    insert(head, numb, size, pos);
    printlist(head);
}
```

I expect the output for the first is 5 then the second is 5 6.

Answer (score 1):

The pointer you pass in `insert(node* head` is just a copy of the pointer in `main`. Any modifications to this pointer (e.g. `head = temp`) will not be reflected in `main`.

You need to pass either a pointer to the pointer or a reference to the pointer, for example:

```
void insert(node*& head, int numb, int size, int pos)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function is invalid and in general has undefined behavior. For example this statement in the function

```
    size++;
```

does not make sense because the parameter `size` does not have a referenced type. That is the function deals with a copy of its argument. The object `size` passed as an argument to the function will stay unchanged. And as a result the variable `size` within main will be always equal to 0.

Or within the loop

```
    node* trail = NULL;
    while (counter++) {
        if (counter == pos) {
            temp->next = current;
            trail->next = temp;
        //...
```

for the position equal to 1 the node trail is equal to NULL so this statement

```
            trail->next = temp;
```

has undefined behavior.

Also the head node in main is not changed by the function because it is passed to the function by value. That is again the function deals with a copy of the head node.

And it is a bad idea to define the variables `size` and `pos` as having a signed integer type. In this case you have to check within the function whether the value of the parameter `pos` is greater than or equal to 0.

The function can be defined as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>

struct node
{
    int number;
    node *next;
};

void insert( node * &head, int number, size_t &size, size_t pos )
{
    node **current = &head;

    while ( pos != 0 && *current != nullptr )
    {
        --pos;
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }

    *current = new node { number, *current };

    ++size;
}

std::ostream & printlist( const node* head, std::ostream &os = std::cout )
{
    for ( const node *current = head; current != nullptr; current = current->next )
    {
        os << current->number << ' ';
    }

    return os;
}

int main() 
{
    node *head = nullptr;
    size_t size = 0;
    size_t pos;
    int numb;

    numb = 5;
    pos = 0;

    insert( head, numb, size, pos );

    printlist(head) << '\n';

    numb = 6;
    pos = 2;

    insert( head, numb, size, pos );

    printlist(head) << '\n';    

    numb = 4;
    pos = 0;

    insert( head, numb, size, pos );

    printlist(head) << '\n';    

    numb = 10;
    pos = 2;

    insert( head, numb, size, pos );

    printlist(head) << '\n';    

    std::cout << "There are " << size << " nodes in the list.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
5 
5 6 
4 5 6 
4 5 10 6 
There are 4 nodes in the list.
```

Pay attention to that you need to write also a function that will free all allocated memory for the list.